# Child routes error with RC6 upgrade

Tags: angular2-routing

I am getting this runtime error with my routing when upgrading to RC6 (this includes child routes):

> ListingComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not
>   been imported into your module

This error indicates that I have not added ListingComponent to ngModule but it is there as a declaration.

In app.module I have all my components as declarations.  I also import my routing component.   The routing component has a sub routing component called listing.routes.

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ReflectiveInjector  } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { NgClass, NgStyle} from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {routing} from './app.routes';
import {ListingModule} from './components/listing/listingmodule';
import {ListingComponent} from './components/listing/listing.Component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, routing],
    providers: [],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ListingComponent, ListingModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Here is my app.routes.ts (which I import as routes):

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ListingRoutes} from './components/listing/listing.routes';
import {SplashComponent} from './components/splash/splash.component';

export const appRoutingProviders: Routes = ([
    { path: '', component: SplashComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: SplashComponent },
    ...ListingRoutes
]);

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutingProviders);
```

And here is my listing.routes.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ListingModule} from './repairreturnmodule';
import {ListingComponent} from '../listing/listing.component';


export const ListingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ListingModule,
        children: [
            { path: 'listing', component: ListingComponent},
        ]
    }
];

export const ListingRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ListingRoutes);
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  you are importing your ListingComponent from

```
import {ListingComponent} from './components/listing/listing.Component';
```

if you using the same convention from the AppComponent (which you should) you should import from

```
import {ListingComponent} from './components/listing/listing.component';
```

See what is the name of the file. The rest of the code looks right.

---

I'm not sure if this is the source of the problem, but you are declaring a module there in the AppModule, when you should be importing it... 
Try moving the ListingModule from declarations array to the imports array.

Comment: okay. sorry and thanks. I made an edit that probably is helpful. is this better?